# How To Format Simple String Output From SQL Server SELECT Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-parsing

We are using SQL Server 2016.

I have a column called TrainerName that contains "Bob Smith".  I would like to perform a SELECT query that would return this column looking like "Smith, Bob".  How can I do this with the SELECT statement?

One small caveat is that the column might contain say "Mary Jane Smith" and I need to have this come out as "Smith, Mary Jane".

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: That's not simple formatting at all. This requires parsing the string, recognizing words and reversing them. Assuming of course there are only *two* words in there, in a predetermined order

Comment: What about "Oscar de la Hoya"? Or any of thousands of other examples where there is no consistent pattern?

Comment: Different countries have different name rules. In some of them the whole 4-5 words are *one* name - there's no first and last name - just ask any travel agent that had to deal with Arabic names

Comment: You have no idea the can of worms you are opening. Names are so much more complicated than they appear at first glance.

Comment: Obligatory reference....https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: This kind of problem requires fuzzy matching and name recognition techniques. Since you use SQL Server 2016 there may be R packages that can recognize the language, pattern and elements of the name. Perhaps with a little help from some extra fields like `Country`. You could use them in a model that receives the input and emits one or more outputs, perhaps with a confidence level. Or just returns the best choice, whatever that is

Comment: On the other hand, if the question is how to *match* names that may be in different order, all you need is a fuzzy matching package, possibly generating a normalized form that can be used for indexing but not displaying. If all you need is to determine whether `Bob Smith` and `Smith, Bob` are the same, a fuzzy matching operation could give you a confidence level based on your data set

Comment: This can of worms can be part of natural language processing or fuzzy matching. It can use machine learning too. Airlines won't let people fly unless the ticket and passport names match, so travel agents can lose a **LOT** of money when customers misspell their names - cancellation fees, lost revenue, call-center costs. Guess how I know ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're doing this so that you can store the data properly into different columns for first and last name.  In this case, it can be a good first step, as there are fewer changes you need to make when you go back and manually clean up names that don't meet your expectations.  If this is not your purpose, you're going to have many headaches anytime you have a requirement come up that involves names.

Assuming this is your purpose, then find the position of that last space, split the first name from the last name using it, and then recombine.

Here's some sample data:

```
declare @trainers table (trainer varchar(255));
insert @trainers values ('Bob Smith'), ('Mary Jane Smith');
```

And here's a query that splits as you desire:

```
select      t.trainer,
            name = names.lastName + ', ' + names.firstName
from        @trainers t
cross apply (select 
                value = len(trainer) - charindex(' ', reverse(trainer))
            ) lastSpace
cross apply (select 
                firstName = left(trainer, lastSpace.value),
                lastName = substring(trainer, lastSpace.value + 2, len(trainer) - lastSpace.value)
            ) names
```

Note that there's not much room for error.  If there is a space in the last name, you need even more complex logic.

Comment: You're assuming a specific country's rules and a predetermined word order

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think my edit came in after your comment, but yes, it's good to give a heads up about this.  But, if he's seeking to properly store this data, then this is probably a good first step.  It'll get most records the way he wants, so that there will be fewer changes he needs to do when cleaning up the rest.

Comment: From Sean Lange's comments https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ You *can't* assume any kind of order. The entire 5-word string could be a *single* name that can't be broken into parts. Ask I mentioned in a comment, ask a travel agent about Arabic names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, if your purpose is as a first step to storing the names correctly, then in an English speaking country the assumption will cover the vast majority of names, thereby saving you a lot of typing when manually parsing the rest of the names.  So I think it's legitimate in this circumstance.  I updated my last paragraph in the answer though to give greater clarity to the warning.

Comment: You assume no foreign customers, or even natives with non-English names. Like *Boris* Johnson. Or `de Havilland`, `de Spencer`, a ton of British names actually. The owner of Manchester City is Sheikh Mansour - title + name. Then there's the Queen

Comment: That's why Soundex was created in the US in the first place, as an attempt to normalize names in a fuzzy way that gives good-enough matches

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: No, I'm not assuming no foreign customers or non-English names.  I'm assuming a TREND of English names.  I explicitly say in the answer that my recommendation is that the OP parse the names using my approach into a table and then manually change the ones in error.  As for soundex, that may be worth a competing answer, with the same warning.  But given that the warning is in there and the recommended circumstance for its use as a first step followed up by manual clean-up, I don't see how your concern is not resolved.

Comment: Thank you @pwilcox  That is exactly what i'm looking for.  There's no way I would have come up with that solution by myself.  Thank you.  :)